# extern "C" DLL_PUBLIC

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to start figuring out how to link a C++ library into an Android project with JNI. I'm taking a look at the example .cpp file included with the library. My C++ is not that good yet but I can understand what's going on, except for one symbol - DLL_PUBLIC. I've tried Google and looking at the MSDN material, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for.

So, what is DLL_PUBLIC telling it to do exactly? It's ok if you tell me to read some documentation, I just need to know what it is and why it can be in the declaration. I understand the #define directive here, but not what the end result means.

```
#define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))

using namespace soundtouch;

extern "C" DLL_PUBLIC jstring Java_net_surina_soundtouch_getVersionString(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    const char *verStr;

    LOGV("JNI call soundtouch.getVersionString");

    // Call example SoundTouch routine
    verStr = SoundTouch::getVersionString();

    // return version as string
    return env->NewStringUTF(verStr);
}
```

Comment: The default character set/encoding on Android is Unicode/UTF-8 so presumably that what `SoundTouch::getVersionStriong()` uses. You might know otherwise but it's doubtful that it uses _modified UTF-8_, which is what `NewStringUTF` uses. `NewStringUTF` won't handle standard UTF-8 generally. One of the `java.lang.String` constructors should work for your strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure *why* you'd mention MSDN, this is a gcc thing. Attributes allow you to add metadata information to objects (functions, variables, types and so on) within the code, such as packing and alignment of structures.

More details on function attributes can be found in the gcc doco [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), including details on the visibility attribute:

> **visibility ("visibility_type")**
>
> The visibility attribute on ELF targets causes the declaration to be emitted with default, hidden, protected or internal visibility.

```
void __attribute__ ((visibility ("protected")))
    f () { /* Do something */; }
int i __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
```

> See the ELF gABI for complete details, but the short story is:
>
> **default:** Default visibility is the normal case for ELF. This value is available for the visibility attribute to override other options that may change the assumed visibility of symbols.
>
> **hidden:** Hidden visibility indicates that the symbol will not be placed into the dynamic symbol table, so no other module (executable or shared library) can reference it directly.
>
> **internal:** Internal visibility is like hidden visibility, but with additional processor specific semantics. Unless otherwise specified by the psABI, GCC defines internal visibility to mean that the function is never called from another module. Note that hidden symbols, while they cannot be referenced directly by other modules, can be referenced indirectly via function pointers. By indicating that a symbol cannot be called from outside the module, GCC may for instance omit the load of a PIC register since it is known that the calling function loaded the correct value.
>
> **protected:** Protected visibility indicates that the symbol will be placed in the dynamic symbol table, but that references within the defining module will bind to the local symbol. That is, the symbol cannot be overridden by another module.
>
> Not all ELF targets support this attribute.